# Responsive full page image (100% height)

Tags: css, height, background-image, responsive

Although there is a lot of content on this specific topic, I've tried the pointers given by others to no avail.

I have a div with the id=headerimg as can be seen here:-

https://jsfiddle.net/9d3bmpxc/1/

as you can see I have used the common css for a full width responsive image:-

```
#headerimg {
    background: url(http://www.adamoxenhamsmith.co.uk/site/img/NewYork.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

As you will see in the JSFiddle link my image is not responsive, Even if I set the min height to 100% nothing happens.

Please also note that the four dots at the top indicate my nav which is not styled.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the height of an element to 100%, you also need to set the height of the parent too (in this case, the body). If you add `height: 100%` to your #headerimg element and the following to your CSS:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

This should display your image with full height.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting my answer. Thanks